# nm-applet disconnects from a known wireless network and fails to reconnect

Tags: wireless, network-manager

I have Samsung R780 laptop with Realtek RTL8192E Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC. I had problems with wireless on it from the beginning: initially, internal wireless adapter would not even work (see [LaunchPad bug #574105](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/574105) I had filed). Then, after some upgrades, it started to work upon loading the system, but then failed to be recognized by the system after suspend.

Now, after 12.04 and 12.10 upgrades it works both upon launch and resume from suspend, and works generally good, although it slows down sometimes. but every now and again (could be several times a day) it disconnects from the network, then tries to reconnect for some time, then pops a window requesting a password, even though it has the correct password saved. After that, it fails to reconnect, and just keeps asking for the password.

It works again after restart (which is a hassle if I had a lot of work to be done), or sometimes (not often) can be fixed by disabling wireless and networking (in various combinations), and then re-enabling them again. If I `killall nm-applet`, and then restart network-manager and nm-applet via the terminal, it prints the following to the console when it happens:

```
** Message: No keyring secrets found for [Network ID]/802-11-wireless-security; asking user.

(nm-applet:[Process ID]): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Now, I am aware of various issues with different flavours of Realtek adapters, about using built-in Linux drivers v. installing proprietary ones via NdisWrapper, about testing upstream kernels and so forth (and all the related questions on AskUbuntu). What I am asking specifically is what exactly that GLib error message entails. I had seen similar issue on all sorts of systems, and relating to all sorts of packages, from nm-applet, to Audacity, and others.

Given better understanding of that, I could better pinpoint the problem or file (or find, which I had failed so far) proper LaunchPad bug for it, methinks.

Comment: I have this happen on a laptop with an intel chip from time to time. Would love to know if there is a fix.